# Finding sum if finite geometric series $a^{n-1}+...+a^2k^{n-3}+ak^{n-2}+k^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am proving a theorem and found here in the following geometric series
$a^{n-1}+...+a^2k^{n-3}+ak^{n-2}+k^{n-1}$ 
what would be the sum of this series.

Comment: Have you seen the expansion of $(a^n-k^n)$ before?

Comment: Like this one for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309692/how-to-factor-an-bn

Comment: I know the formula of sum of finite geometric series, which is $S_n=\dfrac{(a^n)(1-r^{n-1})}{1-r}$

Comment: Yep, so try to use it for $r=\frac{k}{a}$

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{n-1}+...+a^2k^{n-3}+ak^{n-2}+k^{n-1}=\frac{a^n-k^n}{a-k}$$