# How can a power of unknown be expressed as multiple of some polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been preparing for math olympiad recently and I came across this question.

[image]

and I looked up for solution and it said
[image]

Which I do not understand how the power of unknown such as 2013^n - 1803^n can be represented as (2013-1803)u when u is a polynomial. What is u in this equation and what kind of polynomial is it?
Also how does this work?

Comment: This would refer to the identity $a^n - b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b +a^{n-3}b^2 +\cdots+b^{n-1})$, for $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb N^*$. See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309692/how-to-factor-an-bn) for a proof.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are not polynomials; they're just integers. You can factor out $2013-1803$ from $2013^n-1803^n$ for the same reason $x-y$ divides $x^n-y^n$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242) in the linked dupe for a simple way to solve such problems (exploiting the innate symmetry). See the "Linked" questions in the first dupe for further examples. The quoted solution is invoking the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17793/242) $\,a-b\mid a^n - b^n.\ \ $