# Homogenization of curves

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

For example, if we have a conic:$$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$$
how should I homogenise it with a line $y=mx+c$, if my constant $c=0$?
Is it possible to get a pair of straight lines by doing so?

Comment: What means homogenization?

Comment: it means to make the degree of all terms in an equation same using the value of "1" from another linear equation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Does Homogenisation Of An Equation Actually Mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17009/what-does-homogenisation-of-an-equation-actually-mean)

Comment: I think you want to find the equation of pair of lines joining origin to the points of intersection of given line and curve? If that's the (let equation of line be $lx+my+n=0$) set $\frac{lx+my}{-n}=1$ and multiply $2gx$ and $2fy$ with $1$ and $c$ with $1^2$.